# haproxy compression type regex/wildcard

Tags: haproxy, regex, compression, wildcard

As stated in [haproxy docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-compression%20type), we can use "compression type" with list of mime types.

In my case, there is REST API backend, and the compression should be applied to multiple vendor-specific versioned mime types, e.g. `application/vnd.sometype-v10+json` to `application/vnd.sometype-v19+json`. These types are easy to express via regex (or wildcard), but it's very tedious to specify each one in plain list.

Tried to specify different strings such as `.*`, `"application/.*"`, `"application/(.*)"`, but responses had no compression.

Is there a way to use regex/wildcard in "compression type" in haproxy?